# Render to screen and to FBO give different result

Tags: python, opengl, framebuffer, pyopengl

I wrote a program to render a square with texture to screen and to a FBO. I believe the rendering result should be the same for both case, only the output destination is different. Surprisingly, it gives me completely different result.

For the first image, I directly output it to screen. It is good, without any problems. For the second image, I rendered it to a FBO with a texture, and then render that texture to screen. In this case, the output is totally messed up, it seems the output only contain the up-left corner of the image.

[image: First image. Directly render to screen]

[image: Second image. Render to a texture and render that texture to screen]

Related code is:

```
def render(self):
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    gl.glBindFramebuffer(gl.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self._fbids[1])
    gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self._texids[0])
    gl.glUseProgram(0)
    self.drawQuad2()

    gl.glBindFramebuffer(gl.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self._texids[1]) # This is for second, messed up output.
    # gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self._texids[0])   # This is for first, normal output.
    gl.glUseProgram(0)
    self.drawQuad2()

def drawQuad2(self):
    gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS)

    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
    gl.glVertex2f(-1, 1)
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
    gl.glVertex2f(1, 1)
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
    gl.glVertex2f(1, -1)
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
    gl.glVertex2f(-1, -1)

    gl.glEnd()
    gl.glFlush()

def setupTexture(self, num, rawstr, width, height):
    texids = gl.glGenTextures(num)
    for tid in texids:
        print 'texture binded %s' % tid
        gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid)
        gl.glTexImage2D(
            gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0, gl.GL_RGBA, width, height,
            0, gl.GL_RGBA, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            rawstr)
        gl.glTexParameteri(
            gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)
        gl.glTexParameteri(
            gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    return texids

def setupFramebuffer(self, num, texids):
    assert(len(texids) == num)
    fbids = gl.glGenFramebuffers(num)
    for i in range(len(fbids)):
        print 'framebuffer binded %s with texture %s' % (fbids[i], texids[i])
        gl.glBindFramebuffer(gl.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbids[i])
        gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(
            gl.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gl.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texids[i], 0)
    return fbids

def reshape(self, w, h):
    if not h:
        return
    print 'reshape. w:%s, h:%s' % (w, h)

    gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
    gl.glLoadIdentity()

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
    gl.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)

    gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    gl.glLoadIdentity()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `glViewport` function to tell OpenGL the size of the target window it shall address with its drawing operations. So when you switch to render to FBO, you must call `glViewport` with something that makes sense for the target texture; usually the target texture itself. When switching to render to the window you call `glViewport` with the target window size.

If destination viewport is larger than the destination framebuffer this effectively results in a zoom-in.